# Trying to format and print multiple(dynamic) dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, format

When trying to .format() multiple dictionaries in a list at once the console gives me an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'.

I've tried scrolling through the prompted similar questions and all i could find was the reverse: a dictionary of lists.

```
# Algemene voertuiggegevens URL
algemenegegegevensURL = 'https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/m9d7-ebf2.json?kenteken='+'25LXX9'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(algemenegegegevensURL)
algemenegegegevensResult = json.loads(response.read())
data = (algemenegegegevensResult[0])

for key, value in data.items():
    print("{}: {}".format(key, value))

# Voertuigassengegevens URL
assengegevensURL = 'https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/3huj-srit.json?kenteken='+'25LXX9'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(assengegevensURL)
assengegevensResult = json.loads(response.read())

assendata = (assengegevensResult[0:])

for key, value in assendata.items():
    print("{}: {}".format(key, value))
```

Expected result:

```
Key, Value, /Newline.
Key, Value, /Newline.
Key, Value, /Newline.
```

Without brackets.  If there's a single item in the list it seems to work as shown in the data.items(): part.

I tried using [0:] because the list is dynamic and it's not always going to be 2 dictionaries it could range from 1 to maybe 10.

Comment: If `assendata` is a list, then naturally, `assendata.items()` *should* fail, don't you think? Iterate through the list, and then use `.items()` on each item. Keep track of the datatypes you're working with.

Comment: You are correct, i should've been more aware of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assengegevensResult` is a list. Iterate it and then use `.items`

**Ex:**

```
for element in assengegevensResult:
    for key, value in element.items():    #Each dict inside assengegevensResult
        print("{}: {}".format(key, value))
```